# I want to add space between an li element i created using DOM selectors and the button element created along side it

Tags: javascript, dom

How can i add space between the an li element created and the button element created?

```
function createListElement(){
    var li = document.createElement("li"); 
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.classList.add("space") 
    var Delete = document.createElement("button");
    Delete.innerHTML="Delete";
    li.appendChild(Delete);
    Delete.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    })
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    li.addEventListener("click", linecross);
}
```

Comment: i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

jut add some margin left to button

```js
function createListElement(){
    var li = document.createElement("li"); 
    var input =document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var ul =document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.classList.add("space") 
    var Delete = document.createElement("button");
    Delete.innerHTML="Delete";
    li.appendChild(Delete);
     Delete.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    })
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    li.addEventListener("click", linecross);
}

function linecross(){
console.log('linecross');
}

createListElement();
```

```css
button{
margin-left:200px;}
```

```html
<input value=5/>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the style property you can solve it in css

```js
function createListElement(){
  var input = {value:'random text'};
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var li = document.createElement("li"); 
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.classList.add("space") 
    var Delete = document.createElement("button");
    Delete.innerHTML="Delete";
    li.appendChild(Delete);
    Delete.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    })
    Delete.style.marginLeft = '10px';
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    li.addEventListener("click", function(){});
}
createListElement()
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A new problem: If the text i put in my input.value is long then the position of the delete button is farther

Comment: either you supposed to trim the text using `...` for example, Or wrap the text using CSS 
 width property with  `overflow-wrap: break-word;`